# How to enquire a function in another function, not in document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use formvalidation library to validate my forms, and the basic style the developer mentioned is like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myForm1').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        name: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please specify user first name.'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I want to have another function to perform some additional stuff in addition to form validation. How can I enquire form validation inside another function, and not by document ready?

Update: I have a function, which sends information via Ajax. The whole page is loaded in a div, and I want to validate form and send the information by clicking on a button, something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendForm();" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Send it this way">
function sendForm()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'step3.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#dynamicContent').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to add form validation part before calling ajax snippet, but it does not work (not even showing an error message in the console). How can I use form validation?

Comment: Could you clarify? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @NimrodArgov, please see the update. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding the `formValidation` code at the start of `sendForm`?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work.